# Ajax success with html dataType

Tags: javascript, ajax, html-lists

I'm doing an Ajax call with html dataType to a PHP file. The php file answers with html code which includes a `<script>` and a `<li>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ..some code which manages a javascript array
</script>

<li>info about something</li>
```

In the javascript client I need only the `<li>` but when I try to use the data and put it inside a `<ul>` with `id='list'`, I have an error

```
..ajax..
success: function(data){
  $('#list').html(data);
}
..
```

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: Can you share more code? There might be a problem in your JavaScript inside file you loading through AJAX.

Comment: this is a syntax error, write down the the whole file and check your ide it may shows the errors.

Comment: $.ajax({        
    method: 'GET',                                       
    url: 'php/elenco_canzoni.php',      
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data){              
          
    $('#list').html(data);
}

Comment: $.ajax({ method: 'GET', 

url: 'phpelenco_canzoni.php', 
dataType: 'html', 

success: function(data){ 

$('#list').html(data); 

} });

Comment: if I remove the <script> from the php file I don't get the error.
Is it possibile that I should use (data) in different way in the javascript?

Comment: @Yaşar içli I obviously lost it pasting in here.. so it's not the problem!

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({ method: 'GET', 

    url: 'phpelenco_canzoni.php', 
    dataType: 'html', 

    success: function(data){ 

        $('#list').html(data); 

} // <-- });
```

change

```
$.ajax({ method: 'GET', 

    url: 'phpelenco_canzoni.php', 
    dataType: 'html', 

    success: function(data){ 

        $('#list').html(data); 

}});
```

Comment: I lost }); pasting in here... so it's not the problem

Comment: data results html "<script></script> <li></li>"bla bla  code?

Comment: Yes as I pasted the text has been modified. 
I have a php file with
<?php //php code
    <script>
       //javascript code
    </script>
    
    <li> li text </li>

?>

Now I've fixed the initial question

Comment: I fixed my initial question because it wasn't written with the code tags and now is more understandable